# Package a GUI for distribution - ghostscript..?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, ghostscript

I have a GUI created that I'd like to ship out to people I work with. The GUI works perfectly for me, but when I packaged it using pyinstaller and --onefile, it didn't work for anyone else. I am aware no one else has python installed on their machines, but I was told that wouldn't be a problem. However, my program involves ghostscript.

In short, my program has 3 buttons. Button 1 allows the user to select a pdf. Button 2 will convert this pdf into images. Button 3 will read each image and say whether it is a colour page or a black only page, when done it'll delete the temporary image files.

the imports i am using are

```
from tkinter import *
import os, time
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, askdirectory
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst
from PythonMagick import Image as IMG
from PIL import Image
```

I think I'd somehow need to have the user install the same version of ghostscript as me when they open the application. Does anyone have any advice on how I can sort this out to have people use it?

EDIT: When I say 'it didn't work for anyone else', i mean the application opened, the user could select a file, but the button which runs the ghostscript stuff didn't work. Meaning ghostscript needed to be installed. After installed it worked.

Comment: When you say "it didn't work for anyone else", _how_ didn't it work? What was the error?

Comment: the application opened, a file could be selected, but when it came to pressing 'Button 2', nothing happened, the error was ghostscript related because it wasn't installed. when I installed ghostscript it worked, but it's strange because the button does nothing the first time it's pressed, but works the second time. I'm a bit confused really

Comment: It's hard to understand what question you're asking. Are you asking how to bundle ghostscript with your program, or are you asking why the button doesn't work the first time but works the second? Please focus on only one problem at a time.

Comment: @BryanOakley well I'm asking how to bundle ghostscript as the first problem seeing as it somewhat _works_. the second issue is something i can work on once the first issue is done. It just seems no one knows how to handle the first issue.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for pyinstaller? It includes information about how to include additional files with your program.  Though, bundling an entire ghostscript installation may be beyond the scope of pyinstaller.

Comment: @BryanOakley yeah i was aware of that, i was just seeing if there was anyone that had worked their own way around this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest manual installation of GhostScript and adding its path to the OS environment.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

this_path = Path(sys.argv[0]).parent
os.environ['MAGICK_HOME'] = ';'.join([str(this_path / 'image_magic'),
                                      str(this_path / 'GhostScript' / 'bin')
                                      ])
```

Here, I install Image Magic + GhostScript in the root with the Python files.